# RTX 3080 LHR Missing gpu__dram_throughput CUDA metric

Tags: machine-learning, cuda

As part of a machine learning project, we are optimizing some custom CUDA kernels.

We are trying to profile them using Nsight Compute, but encounter the following error running on the LHR RTX 3080 when running a simple wrapper around the CUDA Kernel:

```
==ERROR== Failed to access the following 4 metrics: dram__cycles_active.avg.pct_of_peak_sustained_elapsed, dram__cycles_elapsed.avg.per_second, gpu__compute_memory_throughput.avg.pct_of_peak_sustained_elapsed, gpu__dram_throughput.avg.pct_of_peak_sustained_elapsed

==ERROR== Failed to profile kernel "kernel" in process 20204
```

Running a diff against the metrics available on an RTX 3080 TI (non-LHR) vs an RTX-3080 (LHR) via `nv-nsight-cu-cli --devices 0 --query-metrics`, We notice the following metrics are missing in the RTX 3080 LHR version:

```
gpu__compute_memory_request_throughput
gpu__compute_memory_throughput
gpu__dram_throughput
```

All of these are required for even basic memory profiling using Nsight Compute. All other metrics are correctly present, except for these. Is this a limitation of LHR cards? Why would they not be present?

Details:

- Gigabyte RTX 3080 Turbo (LHR)
- Cuda Version: 11.5
- Driver version: 497.29.
- Windows 10

Comment: `As part of a machine learning project, we are optimizing some custom CUDA kernels.` I am on the same boat! Except, there is no `we` in my case. I got `Failed to access the following 10 metrics` Did you find another solution other than update CUDA version? I am working in Colab with a `Tesla T4` at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Nvidia forums, this is an unintended bug that is fixed by upgrading from CUDA 11.5 to CUDA 11.6, under which all profiling is working correctly with all metrics available.

Successful conditions:

- Gigabyte RTX 3080 Turbo (LHR)
- Cuda Version: 11.6
- Driver version: 511.23.
- Windows 10

We don't know why these metrics were unavailable, but the version update is definitely the correct fix.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post on the nvidia developer forums and from what it looks like, nvidia didn't intend on this, so I'd either just go with what works (non-lhr) for now until they fix it. Quadro and tesla cards are supported by Nsight Compute so they might be a holdover solution.

So to answer the main question:

> Will buying a non-LHR GPU address this problem?

for right now, yes, buying a non-lhr 3080 should fix the issue.